# How to get the position of end -effector of PR2 right arm in the simulator

Tags: robotic-arm, simulation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since we can use Cartesian controller to control the arm of PR2 to move, but how to get the current position of the arm in the simulator? Is it in robot coordination or in world coordination?
If we have a world coordination how to convert to pr2 robot coordination?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30374/how-to-get-the-position-of-end--effector-of-pr2-right-arm-in-the-simulator/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Read up on the [tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) library.

In short: The position of everything can be retrieved in any coordinate frame you want. So you define what frame it is in.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0